# Не могу связать css файл и html

Tags: java, html, css

Всем привет!
Я недавно стал изучать html и захотел улучшить интерефейс страницы связав его с css. Но связать их не получается
вот html файл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот их пути

[image: Где лежат файлы]

Скажите , пожалуйста, почему не могу связать

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: 1) читать легче; 2) можно копировать; 3) поиск работает. Исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Советую почитать как писать пути к файлам http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki
В вашем случаее файл .css лежит отдельно в папке и называется **style.css**, а html документ вне этой папки, но вы в нём вы указали **index.css**.
Правильно должно быть так `href="css/style.css"`

Comment: Ой, это я пробовал разные способы, немного ошибся скриншотом. Данный способ работает, но есть проблема. Если я просто открываю данный html файл, то всё работает. Но если я пробую это сделать через localhost (Например в моём случае http://localhost:8080/systems/1/releases), то сама html страница открывается, все ссылки работают, но все свойства, прописанные в css не видно

Comment: @Саша Попробуй посмотреть в консоли разработчика(Исследовать элемент) в вкладке Elements->Style твои стили css, если их нет, то попробуй почистить кеш: либо Shift+иконка перезагрузки( в некоторых браузерах работает shift+ctrl+r), либо почисти кеш в истории